# Android : how to get the gender and age of the user?

Tags: java, android, google-play, google-play-services

I have got an Android app that I want to auto-setup according the gender and age of the user.

What are the different ways to get the age and the gender of a user ? (which are Google Play policy compliant)

For example, is there a way to get these information through Google Play Services ?

Thanks.

Comment: You can get them through [Google+ API](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people)

Comment: The problem is that PlusClient is deprecated http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/project/2013/271/g1327125/android-studio/sdk/extras/google/google_play_services/docs/reference/com/google/android/gms/plus/PlusClient.html and replaced by GoogleApiClient http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/project/2013/271/g1327125/android-studio/sdk/extras/google/google_play_services/docs/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.html but I don't see how to get the age and gender with it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should use the [`interface Person`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/plus/model/people/Person.html), you'll have everything you need to know about the user. (through `getGender()` and `getBirthday()` (Or `getAgeRange()`)

Edit : 
For using for example let's say getGender(), you would do something around this :

```
 GoogleApiClient client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
         .addApi(Plus.API)
         .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
         .setAccountName("users.account.name@gmail.com")
         .build();


client.connect();
Person.Gender gender;
Person personProfile = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(client);

if (person.hasGender()) // it's not guaranteed
          gender = person.getGender();
```

Comment: @Regis_AG I editied my answer for the sample code you asked, it may be missing some little things since i'm not on my main computer at the moment but it'll do the trick. Have fun !

Comment: Thanks ! I just tried a code close to what you wrote (main difference is that getCurrentPerson must be in a onConnected callback).

I am upset by the results. I tried with 3 different Gmail accounts (mine, the ones of my mother and sister) and most of the Person.getSomething functions return null or something uncomplete/unaccurate. 

getBirthdayDate: returned null in the 3 cases
getAgeRange: returned null 2 over 3 times (one time just a min age (21) far from my real age (36))
getGender: reliable
getCurrentLocation: null
getLanguage: null 1 time, ok 2 times
Conclusion:reliable only for Gender.

Comment: I was thinking back on what you said @regis_ag, but does thoses 3 accounts have setted up their account only in gmail, not in G+ ? Maybe thats why the age doesnt show up. Looking back to your results.

Comment: What I know is that I am what most people call a "geek", I use Google Plus (mostly for photos but I use it), and all Google services (Gmail, Drive, etc....), I have an Android phone and tablet but....this API is not able to know my age, my birthday date, etc... Only my first name/name, language, some of the companies I worked for (mentioned on my G+ account). I am also the person who set up the Gmail/G+ accounts of my mother and idem : no age/birthdate... So : this API is bad to get the age of the average user.

Comment: @Regis_AG damn. I'll keep looking then, this is really strange that you're not getting any output.

Comment: I get some outputs : the gender (all 3 cases), language (2 ou 3 cases), companies names (for my account), lower bound of the age range (for 1 account out of 3), name/first name (all cases), URL of the G+ page (all cases).

Comment: person.hasGender() should be personProfile.hasGender()

Answer (score 3):

An alternative, perhaps more reliable, approach to guessing your user's gender in Android would be hitting a third party API with the email address of your user, then letting the API look for a first name inside the email string, match it against a database of names, then return to you a gender + confidence level.  I used "Gender API" (no affiliation).

Just have to add to AndroidManifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
```

Then get your user's Gmail addresses:

```
Pattern pattern = Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS; 
Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(context).getAccounts();
for (Account account : accounts) {
if (pattern.matcher(account.name).matches()) {

     String emailAddress = account.name
   // grab each of your user's email addresses


 }
}
```

Then, if you want to use the API I used, get a key from gender-api.com and hit this link for each email address:

```
https://gender-api.com/get?email=ANDROID_USER_EMAIL_ADDRESS&key=<YOUR_PRIVATE_KEY>
```

This API returns gender and level of confidence and I'm sure there are others out there that do the same thing.

Comment: This is great, thanks for sharing this. Is there any similar API that would provide an age?

Comment: Have you get any similar API that would provide an age? @AlexVPerl