# google + sign-in in android not working?

Tags: android, google-plus, google-play-services, google-signin, google-plus-signin

Hello all i have posted this question two times now i am posting it again

[How to get user's gender and date of birth by using googleapi client in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33907891/how-to-get-users-gender-and-date-of-birth-by-using-googleapi-client-in-android)

[How to integrate google+ sign in my android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33934362/how-to-integrate-google-sign-in-my-android-app)

how can i get person's gender and date of birth using `google + sign-in` android my code is given below but what is happening is that i am only getting google sign in information but not of `google +` login. If there is some one how has done this google + integration in android please help me it will be really really helpful for me.

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestScopes(new Scope(Scopes.PROFILE))
            .requestScopes(new Scope(Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN))
            .requestProfile()
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
            .enableAutoManage(getActivity(), this)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .addApi(Plus.API)
            .build();
```

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29679406/android-how-to-get-the-gender-and-age-of-the-user

Comment: sorry but no it is not working for me @Lakhan

Comment: what you are getting? any error?

Comment: Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) is returning false

Comment: above question u commented is my same question ??

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, while creating mGoogleApiClient, you have to add permissions to access google plus profile. Add this

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
        .enableAutoManage(getActivity(), this)
        .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
        .addApi(Plus.API)
        .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.PROFILE))
        .build();
```

Once authentication is succesful and user has made his gender public.
Use this to get user's gender.

```
gender = Plus.plusClient.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient).getGender();
```

Comment: le me check whether it is working or not bdw i have set scope above if you can see in the gso but still may be i have to add it in apiclient lets hope it works

Comment: No it is not working for me :(

Comment: but still thanks for your efforts atleast you commented here :)

Comment: Please check if user has made his gender public or not.

Comment: yep i am using my account bdw how to check for public ??

Comment: One more thing. Did you get the SHA-1 fingerprint?

Comment: is above code working for you ??

Comment: Yes, this worked for me.

Comment: SHA-1 fingerprint of what ??

Comment: SHA1 fingerprint is required to obtain API key for Google API projects. Source. http://www.learn2crack.com/2013/12/setup-google-play-services-sha1-fingerprint.html

Comment: as google-sign in is working fine with me i dont think error is in api key ?? also i have added google-services.json in my app