# How can an age restriction be applied to an Android app?

Tags: android

I'm working on an Android app where a user must be 18 years or older to apply.
If there will be people under 18, the app would have negative public view which I do not want to deal with.

Is it somehow possible to be sure that my users are older than 17? Is there any service which could possibly accomplish this?

Ideal fictional solution: in my registration form the user writes his/her id number and I would check if he/she is old enough with fictional service.

One not very good solution which I found. There is an app called Muzmatch. It is dating app for Arabs. When the user register he have to use device camera to take picture of himself and send it to server.

I can do the same in my app and check if the user seems old enough but I think it's stupid idea.

Comment: Can check this link:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29679406/android-how-to-get-the-gender-and-age-of-the-user

Comment: Can you ask your users to make a nominal payment on a debit/credit card, assuming that minors would be unable to obtain such a payment method in their own name?

Comment: Yeah this is probably the best solution to restrict age.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible through the Google Play content rating system.

Check out the link: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/188189?hl=en-GB

Scroll down to the `Take your app’s rating questionnaire` section and it'll run you through the steps to apply an age rating to your app.

In addition to this, maybe you could create a free in app purchase, that the user will have to buy when first entering the app. They would then need either a password or finger print in order to pay via Google Play.

Comment: As I understant when an underage user has parent controll switched off he can still dowload the app. Its not ideal.

Comment: True, i've added another way in which you could possibly achieve this.